# How to run code asynchronously from within an async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

If you call an async function from non-async code, anything after the await runs asynchronously with respect to the caller:

```js
async function asyncInner() {
  console.log('before asyncInner');
  await Promise.resolve()
  console.log('after asyncInner');
}

console.log('start');
asyncInner()
console.log('end');
```

In other words, this prints:

```
start
before asyncInner
end
after asyncInner
```

But if you call this async function *from within another async function*:

```js
async function asyncInner() {
  console.log('before asyncInner');
  await Promise.resolve()
  console.log('after asyncInner');
}

async function asyncOuter() {
  console.log('before asyncOuter');
  await asyncInner();
  console.log('after asyncOuter');
}

console.log('start');
asyncOuter()
console.log('end');
```

you get:

```
start
before asyncOuter
before asyncInner
end
after asyncInner
after asyncOuter
```

In other words, the inner method completes synchronously with respect to the outer method. Why is this and how could it be written so that `asyncOuter` completed before the `asyncInner`?

(I know I could use a `setTimeout` for this, but I'd prefer to avoid using callbacks, because one of the nice things about async is avoiding callback hell.)

Comment: `the inner method completes synchronously `  No it doesn't, that's maybe were your getting confused.

Comment: Awesome clear demo of the behavior you are looking to better understand. Two requests:  
1. Could you clarify precisely what kind of output you would like to get, including all 6 printouts?  
2. Could you reframe your why question into a what or how? This may help you get a clearer answer to what you would like to know (eg. "What specifically causes an async function called within another async function to behave synchronously?")

Comment: @Keith: I see that I was confusing "synchronous" with "waited".

Answer (score 4):

> In other words, the inner method completes synchronously with respect to the outer method. Why is this and how could it be written so that asyncOuter completed before the asyncInner?

It's not actually synchronous, but you're right that it will wait for the inner function to finish before continuing the outer function. The reason it will wait is because you *told* it to wait with the `await` keyword. If you don't want it to wait, simply leave that out.

```js
async function asyncInner() {
  console.log('before asyncInner');
  await Promise.resolve()
  console.log('after asyncInner');
}

async function asyncOuter() {
  console.log('before asyncOuter');
  asyncInner(); // <--------- removed the await
  console.log('after asyncOuter');
}

console.log('start');
asyncOuter()
console.log('end');
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I see that I was confusing "synchronous" and "waited".  What I really want, I realize, is a way to say "let this routine complete and then call the subsequent code". In other words, just syntactic sugar for setTimeout, and await is basically unrelated to this.

Answer (score 1):

> @Keith: I see that I was confusing "synchronous" with "waited".

Even then it's kind of vague.  `await` in Javascript is really some fancy syntax sugar for `promise.then(result => {})`  So nothing really waits, it's just callback hell is converted into something that looks synchronous, and as such much easier to reason with.

It might make more sense if we remove `await`, and do it the old fashioned way of using the `thenable`.

So below I have converted your example to run without `await`, and as you can see it gives the same result, but this time we are using callback's.  So if you understand callback's, it then makes more sense why you get the result you do.

```js
function asyncInner() {
  console.log('before asyncInner');
  return Promise.resolve().then(r => 
    console.log('after asyncInner'));
}

function asyncOuter() {
  console.log('before asyncOuter');
  return asyncInner().then(() => 
    console.log('after asyncOuter'));
}

console.log('start');
asyncOuter()
console.log('end');
```

Comment: This does make it easier to follow, at the cost of parentheses and other callback syntax pain.